# "RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request: reason: invalid patch for uri urlList.json: invalid path: /test/

Tags: node.js, rest, marklogic

I have a marklogic database with the following JSON document named urlList.json

```
{
   "test": {
             "ip": "10.10.10.10", 
             "fqdn": "www.test.test"
            }
}
```

I am trying to add to the test object with the marklogic rest API using patch. I am using Node with the request-promise module here is the code

```
var options = {
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://test:8000/v1/documents',
  qs: { database: databaseName, uri: 'urlList.json' },
  headers:
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
  strictSSL: false,
  auth: {
    user: userName,
    pass: password,
    sendImmediately: false
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "patch": [
      {
        "insert": {
          "context": "/test/",
          "position": "last-child",
          "content": { "test": "test"}
        }
      }
    ]
  })
};

request(options)
  .then(results => {
    return resolve(results);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return reject(err);
  })
```

The desired outcome when it runs is

```
{
   "test": {
             "ip": "10.10.10.10", 
             "fqdn": "www.test.test",
             "test": "test"
            }
}
```

I get the following error every time I run it

```
"400 - "{\"errorResponse\":{\"statusCode\":400, \"status\":\"Bad 
Request\", \"messageCode\":\"RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ\", 
\"message\":\"RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request:  
reason: invalid patch for uri urlList.json: invalid path: /test/\"}}""
```

Here is the body that is sent

```
"{"patch":[{"insert":{"context":"/test/","position":"last- 
child","content":{"test":"test"}}}]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

A path must select a node. For that reason, a path can't end with a separator. That's what the message attempts to convey.

Does it work with a path of `/test`?

By the way, MarkLogic provides a Node.js API with support for promises. That might be easier to work with.